# How to change the setting of apache superset from sqlite to MySQL

Tags: apache-superset

Can anyone provide a steps to Change the setting of apache superset from sqlite to MySQL?

I have create superset_config.py to override the configuration
after adding the property i am able to enabled swagger url
I have added SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql://root:xxxxxx@127.0.0.1:3306/superset' property in superset_config.py file
but still it is connecting with SQLlite.

Comment: If you are using docker make sure you are updating the config in the right path. If you are doing a pip install, then what you are doing should work. Stop and rerun superset.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote article that can help you.
I had problem using docker compose and native installation . Port is closed can be due to networking problem or problem with packages. Host.docker.internal doesn’t worked for me on Ubuntu 22. I would like to recommend to not follow official doc and use better approach with single docker image to start. Instead of running 5 containers by compose, run everything in one. Use official docker image, here [image](https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/superset). Than modify docker file as follows to install custom db driver:

```
FROM apache/superset
USER root
RUN pip install mysqlclient
RUN pip install sqlalchemy-redshift
USER superset
```

Second step is to build new image based on docker file description. To avoid networking problems start both containers on same network (superset, your db) easier is to use host network. I used this on Google cloud example as follow:

```
docker run -d --network host --name superset supers
```

The same command to start container with your database. —network host. This solved my problems. More about in whole step to step tutorial: [medium](https://medium.com/@vladakuc/apache-superset-the-easiest-way-to-start-with-superset-and-custom-database-driver-mysql-7b0702b37643) or here [blog](https://funvision.blogspot.com/2022/10/easy-dockerfile-based-apache-superset.html?m=1)